# Is possible extract vuetify rules in external file to reuse it?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

i'm using vue + vuetify + typescript to build a login/register form.
According to official documentation from vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#creating-rules is possible add custom rules.

My question is: is possible extract this rules in separate files as classes, functions, etc...that could be parametrized from template to reuse it?

Answer (score 2):

You can have your rules written to an external file. Here's an example where the rules are in a js variable:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify)

// or : import externalRules from '@/rules/MyRules.js'
var externalRules = [
  v => !!v || 'Name is required',
  v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters'
]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    valid: true,
    name: '',
    nameRules: externalRules
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        this.snackbar = true
      }
    },
    reset() {
      this.$refs.form.reset()
    },
    resetValidation() {
      this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
        <v-text-field v-model="name" :counter="10" :rules="nameRules" label="Name" required></v-text-field>

        <v-btn :disabled="!valid" color="success" @click="validate">
          Validate
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn color="error" @click="reset">
          Reset Form
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn color="warning" @click="resetValidation">
          Reset Validation
        </v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```